# Validate form with Jquery what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script src='jquery.validate.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" /></br>
    <input type="text" name="field2" /></br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I got this example from one of the answers of a similar question here but something is wrong with me its just doesnt work. Someone will tell me why ?

Comment: do you get a JS error in the console?

Answer (score 1):

`jquery.validate.js` depends on jquery library, so you need to include jquery library before adding jquery validation... so change the script order in your page

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='jquery.validate.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```